# Is there any way to check iCloudDrive is on or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, icloud

Is there any way to find in current device icloudDrive is enable or not ? Actually i am facing issue with file sync with ios 7 and ios 8 icloud.
Right now i have used UIDocument to upload it to icloud.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
id currentiCloudToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
```

"If a user signs out of iCloud, such as by turning off Documents & Data in Settings, **the ubiquityIdentityToken method returns nil**. To enable your app to detect when a user signs out and signs back in, register for changes in iCloud account availability. In your app’s launch sequence, add an app object as an observer of the NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification notification"

[Prepare Your App to Use iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW18)

Comment: Thnaks for ans but i need to check icloudDrive(new version of icloud introduced in ios8) is enable or not..  so i can alert user than now you older version can not sync with icloud account